Как сравнить веденные символы со списком?
Дается вводный символ и список.

"e", ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

Надо сравнить есть ли в списке этот символ, если есть, то выводим True
Мой код:
def is_member(value,lst):
    for i in value:
        if i[0] == value:
            return True
        else:
            return False


return value in lst, этого кода достаточно, цикл не нужен, ничего вообще не нужно, оператор проверки вхождения элемента в коллекцию in встроен в питон изначально.

А в показанном коде lst вообще не используется почему-то

Использовал lst вместо i[0] в сравнении, тоже ничего не получается

Логично что список никогда не может быть равен строке

Вот я и спрашиваю, как можно сравнивать вводный символ со списком? Потому что так строку я не могу сравнить со списком, получается что если каждый новый символ добавлять в пустой список и тогда уже сравнивать списки?

В первом комментарии уже написали как это сделать правильно, ваша функция вообще не нужна

Если ваш код исправлять, то такие исправления: for i in lst:, if i == value:. Сейчас у вас идет сравнение value как бы с самим собой, а не с элементами из lst. Но все это в итоге не нужно, используйте просто оператор in.

Это делается с помощью оператора in, сначала следует символ, а потом список, строка, множество и т.д.
val = 'e'
t = 'ab' # ['a', 'b']
if val in t:
    print('Символ есть в списке')
else:
    print('Символа нет в списке')

